# Why does PHPword setvalue not replacing text in word Doc?

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to edit word document using php ([PHPword](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) library). However, I am not sure why it is not working. The script did not throw any error.

**My Code:**

```php
    <?php 
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    // $phpword = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('test.docx');
    // $templateProcessor->setValues(array('firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Doe'));
    $templateProcessor->setValue('firstname', 'John');
    $templateProcessor->setValue('lastname', 'Doe');
    
    // var_dump($templateProcessor->setValues(array('firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Doe')));
    var_dump($templateProcessor->setValue('lastname', 'Doe'))
    ?>
```

**My word Doc:**
[word doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9jHG.png)

**Output:**
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBgU.png)

I have no idea why it is not working. can you please help me ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setValue()` method will set the value but not return it to var_dump it.

Instead you can add:

```php
$pathToSave = 'path/to/save/file.ext';
$templateProcessor->saveAs($pathToSave);
```

and check the output in the generated document.

Comment: Thank You. it is working now.  Sorry I am not able to vote your answer as I need 15 reputation to vote.

Comment: Glad it's working now. Can save the vote for later. ;) Good luck on your job!